# React.js: Syncing entire state to localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage, storage, reactjs

I’d like to store my app’s state in `localStorage`. Is there a callback or an event that fires on state change? I would use it to call `localStorage.state = JSON.stringify(this.state)`. Possibly, using 0.5 seconds throttling.

[TodoMVC React examples](http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/react/) uses localStorage as a storage. However, it defines saving and removing in event handlers such as `keydown` and `click`. For my case, doing the same would create a lot of boilerplate.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In a [`componentDidUpdate`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentdidupdate) lifecycle method you could serialize the state:

```
componentDidUpdate: function(prevProps, prevState) {
    localStorage.state = JSON.stringify(this.state);
}
```

That code will be run each time the component rerenders (which happens with every props or state change).

Comment: This works nicely for React alone, for anyone trying to do this using React+Flux keep in mind that you need to keep Stores in sync with this as well. In that case you could initialize the state of each Store from localStorage.state, or you could cache each store's data individually.

Comment: That exactly the issue I have @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375718/who-is-responsible-to-fetch-data-from-server-in-a-flux-app-with-caching

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ohujp97v/4/) of this working in a React based TODO MVC example.

Comment: If you evaluate design options, the next point that will matter is the impact of the performance of `stringify`, which is notoriously famous. You might consider having some logic to reduce the number of `stringify` invocations. Cheers!